# Prove two Hom are isomorphic for a torsion R-module where R is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, direct-product

Here is a question from Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra 3rd edition (page 507, Part 1).

$\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{4 . 6 3}$. If $M$ is a torsion $R$ -module, where $R$ is a PID, prove that
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M, M) \cong \prod_{(p)} \operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(M_{(p)}, M_{(p)}\right)
$$
where $M_{(p)}$ is the $(p)$ -primary component of $M$.

I can see $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M, M) = 
\operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(\bigoplus_{(p)} M_{(p)}, M\right) \cong \prod_{(p)} \ \operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(M_{(p)}, M\right)
$$ by the next two theorems, but I have no idea how to proceed next. Any help would be appreciated.

Attached:

**Theorem B-3.38 (Primary Decomposition)**. If $R$ is a PID, then every torsion $R$ -module $M$ is the direct sum of its $(p)$ -primary components:
$$
M=\bigoplus_{(p)} M_{(p)}
$$

**Theorem B-4.8**. Let $R$ be a ring.
(i) For every left $R$ -module $A$ and every family $\left(B_{i}\right)_{i \in I}$ of left $R$ -modules,
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A, \prod_{i \in I} B_{i}\right) \cong \prod_{i \in I} \operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A, B_{i}\right)
$$
via the $\mathbb{Z}$ -isomorphism $\varphi \varphi: f \mapsto\left(p_{i} f\right)\left(p_{i}\right.$ are the projections of the product $\left.\prod_{i \in I} B_{i}\right)$.
(ii) For every left $R$ -module $B$ and every family $\left(A_{i}\right)_{i \in I}$ of $R$ -modules,
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I} A_{i}, B\right) \cong \prod_{i \in I} \operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A_{i}, B\right)
$$
via the $\mathbb{Z}$ -isomorphism $f \mapsto\left(f \alpha_{i}\right)\left(\alpha_{i}\right.$ are the injections of the sum $\left.\bigoplus_{i \in I} A_{i}\right)$
(iii) If $A, A^{\prime}, B,$ and $B^{\prime}$ are left $R$ -modules. then there are $\mathbb{Z}$ -isomorphisms
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A, B \oplus B^{\prime}\right) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(A, B) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A, B^{\prime}\right)
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A \oplus A^{\prime}, B\right) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(A, B) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}_{R}\left(A^{\prime}, B\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : For $p\neq q$, can there be a nonzero morphism $M_{(p)}\to M_{(q)}$ ?

Note that $p$ is invertible in $M_{(q)}$.

Comment: I suppose there can't be, but I don't see why. Could you give further hints?

Comment: I've added a hint